# OpenCV Template Matching for N best matches not working

Tags: c++, opencv

I have been struggling with this for quite a long while and can't seem to find the problem here. Let me try to walk you through the process.

I am trying to obtain the 10 best bounding boxes for my template matching.

Not going to show the entire image here, but here's my `cv::mat` when I loop through the `cv::mat` to search for the lowest values (results)

```
 int a,b;
    for ( a = 0; a < final_image_height; a++){
      for ( b = 0; b < final_image_width; b++){
        if (result_scores_mat.at<float>(a, b) < 70 ){
          printf("%.2f ", result_scores_mat.at<float>(a, b));
        }
      }
    }
```

This gives me some values present in the `cv::mat` with "lower values"

```
68.50 68.93 54.50 68.92 64.62 57.12 62.69 65.86 63.52 68.35 68.65 61.93 69.18 67.69
```

I then move into a loop whereby I called `minMaxLoc()` to find the `minVal (using TM_SQDIFF, so minVal)`

```
for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++){
      minMaxLoc(result_scores_mat, &minVal, &maxVal, &minLoc, &maxLoc, cv::Mat());

      cout<<minVal<<endl;

      // for match_method TM_SQDIFF we take lowest values
      matchLoc = minLoc;
      drawRadius = result_radius_mat.at<float>(matchLoc.x, matchLoc.y); 

      // display source image and result matrix , draw rectangle around highest possible matching area
      cv::rectangle( img_display_mat, matchLoc, cv::Point( matchLoc.x + 2*drawRadius, matchLoc.y + 2*drawRadius), cv::Scalar::all(255), 2, 8, 0);  

      result_scores_mat.at<float>(minLoc.x, minLoc.y)= 255;
    }
```

What I am doing in the last line is replacing the value of the float at the `minLoc`, so that the next loop I run through `minMaxLoc` doesn't locate that point and gives me the next minimum value in the `cv::mat`.

However, I keep receiving such an output with `cout<<minVal<<endl;`

```
54.5003
54.5003
54.5003
54.5003
54.5003
54.5003
54.5003
54.5003
54.5003
54.5003
```

It detects rightly the 54.50 that is present in the `cv::mat`, but I want all the minimum values in the loop.

Is there something wrong I'm doing, or any way around this? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you are replacing minimum value with 255 in wrong way, it means that you detect minimum value correctly, but you replace 255 in wrong position, you should replace below line

```
result_scores_mat.at<float>(minLoc.x, minLoc.y)= 255;
```

by this line:

```
result_scores_mat.at<float>(minLoc.y, minLoc.x)= 255;
```

For knowing that why we replace this lines by each other, you can take a look at the [source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/89d3f95a8eea50acbfb4b8db380d5a4dc8a98173/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/mat.hpp#L1920) of `.at` method.It is like below

```
template<typename _Tp> _Tp& at(int row, int col);
/** @overload
@param row Index along the dimension 0
@param col Index along the dimension 1
*/
```

Comment: well, fantastic catch and spot on! Thank you!