# How to locate an image in another image while ignoring transparent pixels

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to find out if a parent image contains a sub-image somewhere. Not a pixel perfect match, but within some error threshold. However, my sub-image has a transparent background which I am not trying to match.

Let's say my sub-image is a ring with a transparent center. The parent image can contain whatever it wants to inside that transparent center, I just want to be able to locate that ring.

I've tried messing around with opencv's matchTemplate, but whenever I start adding transparent pixels the similarity starts going down.

What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Read the template image unchanged (i.e. BGRA). Then extract the BGR image from the template without the alpha and the alpha separately. Use the alpha channel as a mask in matchTemplate with the BGR template. Read the docs on matchTemplate at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/dfb/group__imgproc__object.html#ga586ebfb0a7fb604b35a23d85391329be.  Also, see for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779288/how-to-template-match-a-simple-2d-shape-in-opencv/61780200#61780200

Answer (score 0):

Drop the alpha (mask) layer before you try `matchTemplate`. An expressive way to do that is:

```
img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGRA2BGR)
```