# Reducing misses on template matching (using transparent template)

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm trying to determine the position of puzzle piece on a puzzle image.
I have

1. an image of a puzzle piece (transparent png)
2. an image of a puzzleboard whith a white outline around the correct position

Firstly i extract the contour on image 1. and use it to draw my final template.
Then i match the final template to the puzzleboard and save some result images.

Here are some examples of the results i'm getting
https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQxnp.jpg

On some of the images, there's clearly a lot of mismatches and for some of the images, increasing the threshold will hide the correct match and some mismatches will remain.

Any tips or thoughts on optimization would be greatly appreciated!

This is my full code:

```
full_image = cv2.imread('puzzle_1.jpg')    
piece = cv2.imread('piece_1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
partial_image = cv2.cvtColor(piece,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(partial_image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
   
template = np.zeros((55, 55, 4), dtype=np.uint8)

cv2.drawContours(template, contours, -1, (255, 255, 255, 255),1)
hh, ww = template.shape[:2]

puzzleP = template[:,:,0:3]
alpha = template[:,:,3]
alpha = cv2.merge([alpha,alpha,alpha])

correlation = cv2.matchTemplate(full_image, puzzleP, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, mask=alpha)

threshhold = 0.98
loc = np.where(correlation >= threshhold)

result = full_image.copy()
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    cv2.rectangle(result, pt, (pt[0]+ww, pt[1]+hh), (0,0,255), 1)
    print(pt)
    
cv2.imwrite('puzzle_piece.png', puzzleP)
cv2.imwrite('full_image_alpha.png', alpha)
cv2.imwrite('full_image_matches.jpg', result)
```

EDIT:
Here's an example of the two files (piece_1.png and puzzle_1.jpg) (this example has many mismatches)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIj7t.jpg

Comment: Post your input and template image, please

Comment: Added link to puzzle_1.jpg and piece_1.png

Comment: **Why are you drawing every match above your threshold?** Makes no sense. It does not exclude small shifts that are also above your threshold. Unless you expect the template to be found in multiple places, just draw the best match for each input image. If you expect multiple matches due to the puzzle appearing multiple times, then you need to loop over the input multiple times, each time blackening out the region around the previous best match so that slight shifts do not still match above your threshold, so that you separate individual matches from matches very close by.

Comment: **Also you need to make the inside of your template transparent also**. So that you are just matching on the puzzle frame shape, which I assume appears in the template. If you do not, then you will get bad matches since the texture inside the template does not match to that inside the correct region in the image due to brightness changes. An alternate, is to convert your image and template to edges and match on those. Or normalize your image and template by subtracting the mean value and dividing by the standard deviation. However, I do not think the latter will work well to normalize well.

Comment: The threshold code is straight from the link you wrote as an answer to my previous question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779288/how-to-template-match-a-simple-2d-shape-in-opencv/61780200#61780200.
I will look at only drawing the best match, but the best match is in reality often not the best match, which is what's confusing me.
The matching is done well before the drawing of rectangles though, so i don't see how it could affect the matching?

Comment: And i am making the template transparent. The loaded piece_1.png is only used to get a contour. I then draw the contour on the template (which is transparent) and use that for matching. I'm not matching using the initial piece image. I have tried saving this contour drawing to a file and it looks perfect, with transparent background.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219378/discussion-between-fmw42-and-ole).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work fine for me on your given image in Python/OpenCV.

- Read the large and small images
- Convert the small image to gray and threshold to binary
- Get the largest contour of the binary image
- Draw that contour as white on black background to use as the mask
- Extract the BGR channels of the transparent small image as the template
- Do the template matching and get the largest match location
- Draw the match box on a copy of the large image
- Save the results

Large image:

[image]

Small image:

[image]

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

# read images
full_image = cv2.imread('puzzle_1.jpg')    
piece = cv2.imread('piece_1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

# convert piece to gray and threshold to binary
partial_image = cv2.cvtColor(piece,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
partial_image = cv2.threshold(partial_image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)[1]

# get largest contour from binary image
contours = cv2.findContours(partial_image.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
contours = contours[0] if len(contours) == 2 else contours[1]
big_contour = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# draw the contour of the piece outline as the mask
mask = np.zeros((55, 55, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.drawContours(mask, [big_contour], 0, (255,255,255), 1)
hh, ww = mask.shape[:2]

# extract the template from the BGR (no alpha) piece 
template = piece[:,:,0:3]

correlation = cv2.matchTemplate(full_image, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, mask=mask)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(correlation)
max_val_ncc = '{:.3f}'.format(max_val)
print("normalize_cross_correlation: " + max_val_ncc)
xx = max_loc[0]
yy = max_loc[1]

print('xmatchloc =',xx,'ymatchloc =',yy)

# draw template bounds and corner intersection in red onto img
result = full_image.copy()
cv2.rectangle(result, (xx, yy), (xx+ww, yy+hh), (0, 0, 255), 1)

# save results
cv2.imwrite('puzzle_template.png', template)
cv2.imwrite('puzzle_mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('full_image_matches.jpg', result)

# show results
cv2.imshow('full_image', full_image)
cv2.imshow('piece', piece)
cv2.imshow('partial_image', partial_image)
cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('template', template)
cv2.imshow('result', result)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

(bgr) Template:

[image]

Mask:

[image]

Largest Match Location:

[image]

Comment: I suggest that you view your intermediate images to see where you are going wrong. My gut feeling is that your contour image that you create for your mask (alpha) is not correct. I also note that the combination of this template and mask would match closely to your white sky except the sky is slightly darker than your white border of the piece.

Comment: Thank you so much, you're a legend.
This works great. Learned a lot from this mini project! haha

Comment: What if i wanted to resize the puzzle piece template.
I've tried doing 
piece = cv2.imread('piece_1.png', cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
piece = cv2.resize(piece, (56, 55))
and changing mask as well
mask = np.zeros((56, 55, 3), dtype=np.uint8)
But then i'm getting a size mismatch error
(-209:Sizes of input arguments do not match)