# Best way to detect GUI buttons using a image file as reference in python/OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

I'm challenging myself to automate somethings playing a game called Pokemon TCG Online.

As I don't know nothing about reverse engineering, I'm trying to use Computer Vision to identify objects and perform tasks.

The GUI of the game is always the same, so I dont have to deal with color variance and other things. My first tought was to use template matching, but, I'm having a problem with false positives.

The other two alternatives I found was using a HAAR Cascade (I found a "bot" of other game that uses it) or using a neural network and train it to recognize every element.

Before I go deep in a way to do it, I would like to find the best way, to avoid time wasting on a non functional way. Also, I don't want to "use a sledgehammer to crack a nut", so I'm looking for a simple and elegant way to do it.

My first aproach was using python and opencv, since both are simple to use, but I'm open to other tools. I know how to use YOLO on python, but I only succeed installing it on Linux and the game runs on Windows.

Thank you very much

The code I'm using:

```
import cv2
import pyautogui
from PIL import ImageGrab

fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc('X','V','I','D') #you can use other codecs as well.
vid = cv2.VideoWriter('record.avi', fourcc, 8, (1440,900))
jogar = cv2.imread("jogar.png",  0)

while(True):
    
    
    img = ImageGrab.grab(bbox=(0, 0, 1000, 1000)) #x, y, w, h
    img_np = np.array(img)
    img_npGray = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #frame = cv2.cvtColor(img_np, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    vid.write(img_np)
    cv2.imshow("frame", img_npGray)
    res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_npGray, jogar, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)
    threshold  = 0.9
    loc = np.where (res >= threshold)
    # pyautogui.moveTo(loc)
    print(loc)
    
    
    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break    

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

[image]

Comment: Show your template matching code. Are you using the mask option in matchTemplate? That should help. See my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63292013/reducing-misses-on-template-matching-using-transparent-template/63294191#63294191

Comment: Template matching well suited for a problem like this. The official docs for OpenCV [have some great tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/master/d4/dc6/tutorial_py_template_matching.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I edited the question and put the code

Comment: @fmw42 , I tried using your code, but i'm getting an error https://pastebin.com/Gem3eCTe

Comment: File "C:/Users/pili_/Documents/Pokebot/main.py", line 43, in <module>
    correlation = cv2.matchTemplate(img_np, template, cv2.TM_CCORR_NORMED, mask=mask)

error: C:\ci\opencv_1512688052760\work\modules\core\src\arithm.cpp:659: error: (-209) The operation is neither 'array op array' (where arrays have the same size and the same number of channels), nor 'array op scalar', nor 'scalar op array' in function cv::arithm_op

Comment: @bfris, The false postives occurred using the OpenCV tutorials

Comment: Show your extracted template and mask. Then explain where the error is located in your code?  Use imshow to review each step to see that the images are as expected.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/nHGeN4p the img_np is the screen record

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/57TQfdD the mask

Comment: https://imgur.com/4rLVgW1 the template

Comment: You need to make the background blue color in your mask into transparent so that you are matching on the shape of the icon/button. The mask will be the alpha channel and will show the shape of the icon/button outline rather than a rectangle of the full template.

Comment: Hi, solved the problem, I was using the wrong size for the mask. But the result is not good as you can see here: https://ibb.co/FzYvP0M It's mismatching the button.

Comment: I removed the background of the template https://ibb.co/TLrtM4d

Comment: https://pastebin.com/L0fi90UW here is the actual code

Comment: @fmw42 can you help me? thank you!

Comment: Your template is now fine with transparent background. What mask did you use?  The problem I see is that the template is larger than the same object in your game image that you posted above. You need to make the template the very same size as in your game image or you need to do multi-resolution template matching.

Comment: See my posts at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779288/how-to-template-match-a-simple-2d-shape-in-opencv/61780200#61780200 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59759374/cv2-matchtemplate-finds-wrong-template-in-image/59779209#59779209

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I said the tutorials in the official docs were great in my comment. And they are. But you have do some searching for the sample images. Many of them [are here including the Messi picture](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/master/samples/data) used for the template matching tutorial.

This code works. If you are using TM_SQDIFF, then the best match will be found as a minimum. Also, you probably want the best match using cv2.minMaxLoc, rather than using a threshold.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

screenshot = cv2.imread("screenshot.png", 0)
template = cv2.imread("template.png",  0)

res = cv2.matchTemplate(screenshot, template, cv2.TM_SQDIFF)

# threshold  = 0.1
# loc = np.where (res >= threshold)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

print(min_loc)
```

which gives

```
(389, 412)
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Template

[image]