# OpenCV Template Matching for backgammon checker positions

Tags: python, opencv, object-detection, template-matching, game-automation

I am trying to analyze backgammon board and output number of checkers on each position for both players in this format:

```
    "o": {
      "6": 5,
      "8": 3,
      "13": 5,
      "24": 2
    },
    "x": {
      "1": 2,
      "12": 5,
      "17": 3,
      "19": 5
    }
  }
```

Board Image:
[image]

Checker Image:
[image]

Output:
[image]

Code:

```
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
img_rgb = cv.imread('./board.png')
assert img_rgb is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()"
img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img_rgb, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
template = cv.imread('./black.png', cv.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
assert template is not None, "file could not be read, check with os.path.exists()"
w, h = template.shape[::-1]
res = cv.matchTemplate(img_gray,template,cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = 0.6
loc = np.where( res >= threshold)
for pt in zip(*loc[::-1]):
    print(pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h)
    cv.rectangle(img_rgb, pt, (pt[0] + w, pt[1] + h), (0,0,255), 0)
cv.imwrite('res.png',img_rgb)
```

As you see issue is that not all checkers get matched and also so far its not quite clear how to count number of checkers on each position. Any advice would be helpful. Thanks

Comment: that's because you are also including the backgamon base as well in the image, try to only match the circular surface

Comment: Your template circle is not the same size as the circles in your image. The template circle is much smaller. Template matching does not work well unless the sizes match.  It is not scale invariant. Also a black template circle will not match well to a white circle.  Are you trying to get only the black pieces or all pieces? Also you have different backgrounds even for black circles on the board. This will reduce your match score. You should make a white circle on black background as a mask and use the mask in your cv2.matchTemplate.

Comment: @fmw42 for now i am just trying to match all black chekers. i have separate template for white checkers.

Comment: @roglol See for example, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61779288/how-to-template-match-a-simple-2d-shape-in-opencv/61780200#61780200

Comment: yeah you'll need to define binary masks (or alpha channels) for your templates. just open them in an image editor and erase the background around the pieces. save with alpha channels, make sure to imread accordingly, then split into the color and alpha components and pass the alpha as the "mask" to matchTemplate.

Comment: @fmw42 just tried your code and it performs perfectly for black checker template, however performance is terrible for white checkers matches are everywhere on the image. what could be the reason?

Comment: @fmw42 fixed in the case of white checkers i just dont use mask at all. how difficult would it be to read number on dices?

Comment: Template matching is not rotation invariant. So finding the dice will be hard. Perhaps make a template for a black spot surrounded by small amount of white.  Find all the spots and then their distribution. Close spots are on one dice. Far spots are on separate dice.